# How to uninstall this fancy bathroom faucet?

Tags: faucet

I have this faucet that is leaking right at the top.

[image: Picture of faucet under bathroom sink]

The top of the faucet looks like this

[image: Top of the Faucet]

Can someone please help me on:

- How do I remove this?
- Do I have to replace the entire faucet or can this be repaired or replaced independently?
- Help me understand how to remove that ring on top, if indeed that is what needs to be unscrewed as it seems to have a layer of glue sealing it to the sink.

Comment: You *see* the leak below. It's almost certainly leaking from the movable parts of the valve (above), which should be serviceable without removing the valve from the sink.

Comment: pull off the clip (it is just to the right of the words `here too !`) ... then pull down on the ring with the two ears just above the clip

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to remove that small cap at the very top of the cold water valve. Try to pry it off with a small screwdriver. There should be a brass screw inside there, remove it to remove the handle. Then the cone should lift off or unscrew counterclockwise. That should expose the valve stem. There's packing and washers that would need to be replaced or you might have to replace the valve stem. Look for a good plumbing supple store. Remember to turn off the water to that faucet before removing any parts. Water is probably seeping out through the top and dripping out the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That cap does not want to come off! I almost seems like it's one piece with the top handle. I can keep trying, but wanted to post back to see if that may indeed be the way to open this. So far I have managed to dent the cap.

Comment: @Senthil  have you tried soaking the cap with CLR or some other line dissolver like lemon juice?  I can't imagine that cap not popping off.